# How to get access to SelectedItem in Nested Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, listbox

I'm trying to get access to the SelectedItem and also to the Command binded to a nested ListBox inside an ItemsControl. Below is the simplified XAML.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Partials}"                            
</ItemsControl>

<DataTemplate x:Key="Partials">
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItems}"  
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" >

       <ListBox.InputBindings>
             <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteSelectedItemCommand/>
       </ListBox.InputBindings>
   </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is what I have in the VM (simplified)

```
private void FillList()
{
   //Populate the list
    Collection.Add(Data);

    var ListBoxViewSource = new CollectionViewSource { Source = ListBoxDataSource};
    Collection.ListBoxItems= ListBoxViewSource.View;
}

private ObservableCollection<Scene> _collection= new ObservableCollection<Scene>();
public ObservableCollection<Scene> Collection
{
    get { return _collection; }
    set
    {
       if (value != _collection)
       {
           _collection= value; RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
 }

private string _selectedItem;
public string SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set { _selectedItem= value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}

public RelayCommand DeleteSelectedItemCommand { get; private set; }
private void DeleteSelectedItem()
{
    SourceData.Remove(SelectedItem);
}
```

How can get the value of the SelectedItem in the listbox?

Comment: Are you getting any binding error in output window?

Comment: I think no need to declare a DataTemplate like that.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem you're having, and a precise description of what that code does and what you'd like it to do instead. Asking how you can make the bindings work isn't helpful unless you say exactly what they will do when they do "work".

Answer (score 0):

1. To get SelectedItem, you have to use a property in your DataContext class.
2. You are using ListBoxes as items, so you have to declare a property in your inner DataContext.
3. You can also use RoutedEvent ( ListBox.SelectionChanged )  at ItemsControl level to get SelectedValue from ListBox.

Sample :

ViewModel

```
public class StateVM
    {        
        public List<CountryStates> Collection { get; set; }
        public StateVM() { Collection = new List<CountryStates>(); }
    }

public class CountryStates
    {
        public string SelectedState { get; set; } /* SelectedItem will arrive here */

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> States { get; set; }
    }
```

XAML

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Partials">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding States}"  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedState}">
        <ListBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteSelectedItemCommand}"/>
        </ListBox.InputBindings>
    </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsControl x:Name="CountryStateList" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
              ListBox.SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Partials}">
</ItemsControl>
```

CodeBehind

```
StateVM vm = new StateVM();
vm.Collection.Add(new CountryStates() { Name = "India", States = new[] { "mp", "up", "tn" }.ToList() });
vm.Collection.Add(new CountryStates() { Name = "USA", States = new[] { "new york", "washington" }.ToList() });

CountryStateList.DataContext = vm;
```

...

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox source = (ListBox)(e.OriginalSource);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(">>>>>> " + ((CountryStates)(source.DataContext)).SelectedState);
}
```